# IGrouping<TKey,TElement> Totals

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SqFeet { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPerFoot { get; set; }
}
```

I have a List of the that model:

```
private List<MyModel> _myList;

public List<MyModel> MyList
{
    get { return _myList; }
    set
    {
        _myList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I group on this list:

```
var groupBy = MyList.GroupBy(l => l.Name);
```

Now my question: is it possible to show different totals for differnt properties in `MyList`; so what i'm asking is I would like to see the average CostPerFoot the total feet and the total cost. how can i do this?

Comment: Since you explicitly also put the grouping by name in your question you want the values you asked for each grouping?

Comment: can you explain what you are asking?

Comment: Basically I was asking if you want what Arturo is telling you in his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the totals for each group creating an anonymous type with the average of `CostPerFoot`, total sum of `SqFeet` and total sum of `cost`:

```
var totals = MyList.GroupBy(l => l.Name).Select(g => new
{
    Name = g.Key,
    AverageCostPerFoot = g.Average(m => m.CostPerFoot),
    TotalFeet = g.Sum(m => m.SqFeet),
    TotalCost = g.Sum(m => m.Cost)
});
```